# Symfony, in remote host: Error 500. Unknown record property / related component "algorithm" on "sfGuardUser"

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

after deploying, i get the error below after loggingin.

Sf 1.3, sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. And i have this schema.yml in config/doctrine:

```
Usuario:
  inheritance:
    extends: sfGuardUser
    type: simple
  columns:
    username:
      type: string(128)
      notnull: false
      unique: true
    nombre_apellidos: string(60)
    sexo: string(5)
    fecha_nac: date
    provincia: string(60)
    localidad: string(255)
    email_address: string(255)
    fotografia: string(255)
    avatar: string(255)
    avatar_mensajes: string(255)
  relations:
    Usuario:
      local: user1_id
      foreign: user2_id
      refClass: AmigoUsuario
      equal: true



500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException Unknown record property / related component "algorithm" on "sfGuardUser" stack trace

    * at ()
      in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php line 55 ...
              52.      */
              53.     public function filterGet(Doctrine_Record $record, $name)
              54.     {
              55.         throw new Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException(sprintf('Unknown record property / related component "%s" on "%s"', $name, get_class($record)));
              56.     }
              57. } 
    * at Doctrine_Record_Filter_Standard->filterGet(object('sfGuardUser'), 'algorithm')
      in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php line 1382 ...
            1379.             $success = false;
            1380.             foreach ($this->_table->getFilters() as $filter) {
            1381.                 try {
            1382.                     $value = $filter->filterGet($this, $fieldName);
            1383.                     $success = true;
            1384.                 } catch (Doctrine_Exception $e) {}
            1385.             }
    * at Doctrine_Record->_get('algorithm', 1)
      in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php line 1337 ...
            1334.                 return $this->$accessor($load);
            1335.             }
            1336.         }
            1337.         return $this->_get($fieldName, $load);
            1338.     }
            1339.
            1340.     protected function _get($fieldName, $load = true)
    * at Doctrine_Record->get('algorithm')
      in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/record/sfDoctrineRecord.class.php line 212 ...
             209.         return call_user_func_array(
             210.           array($this, $verb),
             211.           array_merge(array($entityName), $arguments)
             212.         );
             213.       } else {
             214.         $failed = true;
             215.       }
    * at sfDoctrineRecord->__call(array(object('sfGuardUser'), 'get'), array('algorithm'))
      in n/a line n/a ...
    * at sfGuardUser->getAlgorithm('getAlgorithm', array())
      in SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/model/doctrine/PluginsfGuardUser.class.php line 96 ...
              93.    */
              94.   public function checkPasswordByGuard($password)
              95.   {
              96.     $algorithm = $this->getAlgorithm();
              97.     if (false !== $pos = strpos($algorithm, '::'))
              98.     {
              99.       $algorithm = array(substr($algorithm, 0, $pos), substr($algorithm, $pos + 2));
    * at PluginsfGuardUser->checkPasswordByGuard()
      in SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/model/doctrine/PluginsfGuardUser.class.php line 83 ...
              80.     }
              81.     else
              82.     {
              83.       return $this->checkPasswordByGuard($password);
              84.     }
              85.   }
  86.
    * at PluginsfGuardUser->checkPassword('m')
      in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/sfGuardValidatorUserByEmail.class.php line 28 ...
              25.     {
              26.       // password is ok?
              27.
              28.       if ($user->checkPassword($password))
              29.       {
              30.
              31.           //die("entro");
    * at sfGuardValidatorUserByEmail->doClean('m')
```

Here you have also my frontend_dev.log

> Apr 15 07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute
>   "sf_guard_signin" (/login) Apr 15
>   07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute
>   "sf_guard_signout" (/logout) Apr 15
>   07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfPatternRouting} Connect sfRoute
>   "sf_guard_password"
>   (/request_password) Apr 15 07:15:23
>   symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting}
>   Match route "sf_guard_signin" (/login)
>   for /login with parameters array ( 
>   'module' => 'sfGuardAuth',  'action'
>   => 'signin',) abr 15 07:15:23 symfony [info] {sfFilterChain} Executing
>   filter "sfRenderingFilter" abr 15
>   07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfFilterChain} Executing filter
>   "sfCommonFilter" abr 15 07:15:23
>   symfony [info] {sfFilterChain}
>   Executing filter "sfExecutionFilter"
>   abr 15 07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfGuardAuthActions} Call
>   "sfGuardAuthActions->executeSignin()"
>   abr 15 07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {Doctrine_Connection_Mysql} exec : SET
>   NAMES 'UTF8' - () abr 15 07:15:23
>   symfony [info]
>   {Doctrine_Connection_Statement}
>   execute : SELECT s.id AS s__id,
>   s.username AS s__username,
>   s.nombre_apellidos AS
>   s__nombre_apellidos, s.sexo AS
>   s__sexo, s.fecha_nac AS s__fecha_nac,
>   s.provincia AS s__provincia,
>   s.localidad AS s__localidad,
>   s.email_address AS s__email_address,
>   s.fotografia AS s__fotografia,
>   s.avatar AS s__avatar,
>   s.avatar_mensajes AS
>   s__avatar_mensajes FROM sf_guard_user
>   s WHERE (s.email_address = ?) LIMIT 1
>   - (f@m.com) abr 15 07:15:23 symfony [err]
>   {Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException}
>   Unknown record property / related
>   component "algorithm" on "sfGuardUser"
>   abr 15 07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfWebResponse} Send status "HTTP/1.1
>   500 Internal Server Error" abr 15
>   07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfWebResponse} Send header
>   "Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=utf-8" abr 15 07:15:23 symfony
>   [info] {sfWebDebugLogger}
>   Configuration 16.42 ms (8) abr 15
>   07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfWebDebugLogger} Factories 123.17 ms
>   (1) abr 15 07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfWebDebugLogger} Action
>   "sfGuardAuth/signin" 211.86 ms (1) abr
>   15 07:15:23 symfony [info]
>   {sfWebDebugLogger} Database (Doctrine)
>   0.01 ms (2)

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score -1):

If you change the field names, the entire plugin will break. You will need to rollback those changes, or rewrite every call of `$user->getId()`, `$user->getUsername()`, etc

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand you.. What field names am i changing? Why the error is only in the remote host? I've just added the frontend_dev.log at the end of my question.

Comment: Things like `location` changed to `provincia`

Comment: sorry, but where is 'location' ?

Comment: That was what the field was originally called. I give up.